# control MIME type for downloads in Domino

Tags: lotus-domino

When downloading a JSON file from a Domino server (from the filesystem's `domino/html` directory, not from an `.nsf` file), its headers are not appropriate.  I'm getting

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

instead of

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

How can I set it to `application/json` (or anything else)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Domino/Data folder, you'll see a configuration file named `httpd.cnf`. Add the following line at the end of that file, just before the fallback rule.

```
AddType .json      application/json                     # JSON
```

(Of course, you need to restart HTTP task after that.)

Comment: That's right. Some parts of HTTP are quite similar.

Comment: I remember hearing back around version 4.5 or 4.6 that Domino's HTTP stack was based on Apache... I never expected to find an `httpd.conf` though.  (Actually, Domino drops the `o` for some reason, so it's strangely `httpd.cnf`... oh! of course: back then people still followed Windows' 8.3 rule...)

Comment: Ah. That's my mistake! Correcting that.

Comment: The stack in Domino has gone through a few iterations. I don't recall what it was in 4.5/4.6, but it was an IBM stack (based on their own port of the CERN stack) for a while, and then it got changed to one based on Apache.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a 'File Identification' Document to the Domino Directory.

Goto the 'Web\File Identifications' folder and click 'Add File Identification'.

Example:

MIME type: application
MIME subtype: json
File extension: json

This would allow Domino to correctly process .json files.